# run a powershell script

Tags: c++, powershell, execute

I am trying to write a C++ code that uses PS to write to the console, send emails, lock directories, etc.

I currently am using a file to execute the scripts with the following code:

```
std::string script = "powershell -executionPolicy bypass -file \"MYFILE.ps1\"";

    system(script.c_str());
```

But I would like to run the script directly from the code using a hard-coded string, something like this:

```
std::string script = "write-host \" 2 \" ";

ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, NULL, script.c_str(), NULL,SW_NORMAL );
```

I expect it to write 2 to stdo, but instead I get 'My Documents' opened.

Comment: Does `ShellExecute` use powershell? Wouldn't it expect a binary to run? Also (and I'm not a Windows guy) but does it make sense to pass the fourth argument to `ShellExecute` without the third argument?

Comment: Managed C++ or native C++?

Comment: @TravisPlunk native